# Scala indexOf accepts everything

Tags: scala

I wrote this into a REPL:

```
case class Thingy(s: String)
val things = List(Thingy("x"), Thingy("y"))
things.indexOf("x")
```

That returns `-1`. But I would have expected it not to compile, because `"x"` is a `String`, not a `Thingy`. In fact, it turns out it doesn't matter what type you put into `indexOf`:

```
things.indexOf(42)
things.indexOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())
```

These all return -1.

`indexOf` has this signature:

```
def indexOf[B >: A](elem: B): Int
```

I thought `>:` means `B` should be a supertype of `A`, but none of these classes are a supertype of my case class `Thingy`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`B` is inferred as `java.io.Serializable`, which is a supertype of both `String` and `Thingy`.<sup>1</sup>

This is an unfortunate consequence of two things:

1. Scala's superfluous parent types that all/most values share (`Any`, `Object`, `Serializable`, et al).
2. `List` being covariant.<sup>2</sup>

To define `indexOf` as

```
def indexOf(elem: A): Int
```

would put `A` in a contravariant position, which isn't allowed<sup>3</sup> because it would violate the Liskov substitution principle: A `List[Thingy]` is a `List[Any]`, and you can call `.indexOf("x")` on a `List[Any]`, therefore you should be able to call `.indexOf("x")` on a `List[Thingy]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> If they didn't both happen to implement `Serializable`, it would still infer `Any`.

<sup>2</sup> This is a reason to prefer invariant collections, such as `scalaz.IList`.

<sup>3</sup> Try it - it won't compile: `trait Foo[+A] { def bar(a: A) }`

Comment: OK, but why, then? If everything you throw at it gets inferred to `Any`, what's the point of having a type at all?

Comment: Updated answer with more detail.

Comment: It's not entirely unfortunate, as there are situations where this is useful. If you have a list of Employees and a Person object and you want to check whether the person is in the list, this wouldn't work if the parameter type is Employee, assuming Employee is a subtype of Person.

Comment: @KimStebel I think the problem stems from the fact that `Serializable`, `Any`, `Object`, et al exist. Updating the answer to place blame where it is due...